# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext

Tags: java, reactor

The subscribe method seems to give an nullpointerexception, after the filter method. When I remove the filter method everything is working fine. Why?

```java
        Flux<String> flux = new Flux<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(CoreSubscriber<? super String> coreSubscriber) {
                coreSubscriber.onNext("Test 7");
                coreSubscriber.onNext("test 6"); //line 33
                coreSubscriber.onNext("test 5");
                coreSubscriber.onNext("test 4");
                coreSubscriber.onNext("test 3");
                coreSubscriber.onNext("test 2");
                coreSubscriber.onNext("test 1");
                coreSubscriber.onComplete();
            }
        };

        flux
            .filter((s) -> s.contains("7"))
            .subscribe(System.out::println); //line 45
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:100)
    at com.douma.reactor.App$1.subscribe(App.java:33)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter.subscribe(FluxFilter.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6873)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith(Flux.java:7040)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6866)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6830)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6773)
    at com.douma.reactor.App.test2(App.java:45)
    at com.douma.reactor.App.main(App.java:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the initial value of your `Flux` container inside the `subscribe` method. When you call `filter`, the initial value is still `null`, so `contains` throws the exception. Add this to your code:

```
    flux.startWith("starter string")
        .filter((s) -> s.contains("7") || s.contains("starter"))
        .subscribe(System.out::println); // Prints out "starter string" and "Test 7"
```